# How to let SymmetricDS filter data load by externalId of target engine

Tags: symmetricds

I'm using SymmetricDS 3.7.

What I want to do is, make SymmetricDS only send data to the client engine, if the external Id of the target node equals a column in the table (multi tenancy). This means, that on server I want to have all rows, but on client side only those ones that belong to the client.

I found out, that I have the engine object in my beanshell script. But it seems as if this is the server (sender) node and not the client engine instance.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the column match router as explained in the user guide: http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_router_types

have a column in the table that is synced to target machines with value which matches the externalId of the target machine

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for... Didn't notice that in the docs. I'll try it out and mark your answer as the solution than. Thanks a lot for your fast response !

Answer (score -1):

yes. first you need to have column in youre table for id of node (store_id or client_id), if there are 2 table (master/detail) only add this column in master.
in table sym_router create router:

```
routerid:myatble_header
source_node_group_id:corp
target_node_group_id:store
router_type:subselect
router_expression:c.external_id in (select :store_id)   -> for mysql ( somthing like for other databases)
create_time:now
last_update_time:now

routerid:myatble_detail
source_node_group_id:corp
target_node_group_id:store
router_type:subselect
router_expression:c.external_id in (select store_id from header_table where id=:id)   -> id is primary key and :id is primary of your detail table.
create_time:now
last_update_time:now
```

now in sym_trigger_router:

```
trigger_id: triger_id for your table that defined in sym_trigger table.
router_id:myatble_header (defined in previous step)

trigger_id: triger_id for your detail table that defined in sym_trigger table.
router_id:myatble_detail (defined in previous step)
```

---